# Slow query, index present

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

This query is executed many times as part of an application, but runs slow:

```
SELECT [c2], [c1], [c5], [c4], [c3], [c6]
  from [MyBigTable]
 where [c7] = 1
   and [c3] in ('a','b','c','d','e')
   and [c4] is not NULL
```

It takes routinely more than 3 seconds, which is already bad, but sometimes the IN has 250 arguments, and the query takes more than one minute.
This is the estimated execution plan:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJ-b2XalH

Table has 11 millions rows.

- In about 11% of rows [c3] and [c4] are both not null.
- In about 88% of rows [c3] is null and [c4] is not null.
- In only 0.4% of rows [c3] is not null and [c4] is null.
- Both [c3] and [c4] can never be null at the same time.
- [c7] is 1 in 97% of cases

There is a nonclustered index on [c3], [c4], [c7], [c8] (in order) including [c2], [c5], [c6]

Every time the query has to be run, the PHP code prepares a SQL statement, executes once and discard. I am discussing with the coders whether this can be improved, but I don't hold my breath.

What can I do to improve the performances of the query?

Could a conditional index, "WHERE [c7]=1 AND [c4] is not NULL" seriously improve the situation?

Comment: do you by any chance also have the actual execution plan? Even of the one where it takes ~3 seconds would be helpful.

Comment: Some options would be by either pressing `CTRL+M` and then running the query or using the profiler to capture the plan xml while the app runs the query. More information on both [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan). The reason I am asking for the actual query plan is because I don't see anything wrong with the estimated plan given atm. Even though the `where [c7] = 1` is a residual predicate, I'm not sure if that would be the issue. The filtered index might help due to the `OR` happening between the `IS NULL` and the `IN` operator

Comment: Are you sure the query is executed as is in your question? Is there a chance that it will be parameterized by the PHP code or by `forsed parameterization` option? `select is_parameterization_forced from sys.databases WHERE name = 'YourDbName'`

Comment: is_parameterization_forced is 0

Comment: How is the `IN` clause being generated?  Is this being done programmatically via an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) such as [LINQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) or [NHibernate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate)?

Comment: if the IN predicate always contains a non-NULL list, then create a filtered index against c3 and c4 where both are not NULL.  Then you will limit the I/O down to your 11%.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide datatype of columns and real scenario.

Real scenario like How you are passing c3 value and other values ?

Since `c4 is not null` in 88% of cases   and `[c7] = 1` in 97% of cases

It is ideal scenario to create `Filtered Index`.

I am little bit confuse whether you should create `Filtered index` on each column separately or create `Composite Filtered Index`.

May be do the experiment yourself.

`Composite Filtered Index`,

```
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCI_c7_c4
   ON dbo.MyBigTable(c3)
   INCLUDE([c2],[c1],[c5],[c6])
   WHERE [c7] = 1 and [c4] is not NULL
```

> IN has 250 arguments

It is better to put `c3` in `#temp` table and use `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT [c2], [c1], [c5], [c4], [c3], [c6]
  from [MyBigTable] A
  LEFT JOIN #temp T on A.c3=T.c3
 where [c7] = 1
   and [c4] is not NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

Try writing this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl ([c3] CHAR(1));

INSERT INTO #tbl([c3])
SELECT 'a' UNION ALL
SELECT 'b' UNION ALL
SELECT 'c' UNION ALL
SELECT 'd' UNION ALL
SELECT 'e';

SELECT [c2], [c1], [c5], [c4], [c3], [c6]
  FROM #tbl AS t
  INNER JOIN [MyBigTable] AS MBT ON MDB.[c3]=t.[c3]
 WHERE [c4] IS NOT NULL
   AND [c7] = 1;

DROP TABLE #tbl;
```

Moreover, if there is a lot of data in the temporary table #tbl, then after inserting all the data, create a clustered index across the field c3.